Why would a late check-in require the passenger's signature on the bag tag?
I see this bag tag in this answer by lambshaanxy:



Why would a late check-in require the passenger's signature on the bag tag?

It might not for that situation. Looks like a multi-purpose tag and perhaps only some of the boxes need a signature.

Rather than asking two very related questions, why not merge them into one question?

Passenger's signature is a confirmation of a fact. These check boxes describe various situations under which the airline's obligations to the customer may change from what's under the usual conditions of carriage (that's what "limited release" means).
For example, if you checked your luggage in late and as the result it wasn't loaded on the plane you're flying on - that may be your fault and you may not be entitled to the compensation you'd otherwise be entitled to. By signing this slip you're confirming you're aware of the changes in the conditions of carriage that are applicable to your specific situation. The changes themselves would probably depend on the airlines involved, and the laws in the jurisdictions applicable.
Similarly, if you sign that the luggage was already damaged at check in - you will not be able to demand compensation for damaged luggage when you get it back at your destination.
Given that, according to this post, you've experienced signing this confirmation, you'd be the best person on this forum to explain what are the changes that were applicable to you, under what conditions, how this was presented to you, what additional explanation you got, and what additional paperwork was provided to you. By your repeated questions on this topic it appears that you haven't actually asked the people asking you to sign what it is that you're signing, and instead expect random strangers on the internet to guess.

"By your repeated questions on this topic it appears that you haven't actually asked the people asking you to sign what it is that you're signing" unfortunately I forgot. I got distracted by asking a few other questions. It's a bummer as the staff at that time seemed very knowledgeable.
